# Change cell color of full calendar in AgendaWeek only

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to change the cell color of my full calendar in AgendaWeek view only. I found some posts, but it only used basicWeek.Can anyone help? My month view color is changing fine with the following event I added:

```
 dayRender: function (date, cell) {
                cell.css("background-color", "grey");
                               },
```

Note: I dont want to change the color of the event but the cell color itself.

Comment: fiddle please . or post source code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using viewRender callback to add and remove a class from your calendar object when the views are rendered:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/739j8tuL/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        ...
        viewRender: function(view, element){
              if(view.name == "agendaWeek"){
                $("#calendar").addClass('agenda-week');             
              }else{
                $("#calendar").removeClass('agenda-week');              
              }},
            currentLangCode: 'de',
        ...
    });
});


<style>
    #calendar.agenda-week .fc-day{
      background-color: grey;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Works immaculately perfect!! Great.

Comment: @scottysmails Can you help me with this ?

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586848/hightlight-cells-in-full-calendar-based-on-start-date-and-end-date-in-agendaweek)