# Change cell background in fullCalendar agenda view based on start and end of a selection event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

[image]

Is it possible to highlight cells in full calendar based on start and end date in agendaWeek view. Any help is really appreciated. My problem is in select event, based on start and end time i want to change the color of cells based on end and start time, just like when i add an event.
Thanks in advance.

```
 var calendar = $('#eventCal').fullCalendar({

            header:{left:'prev,next today', center:'title', right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'},
            selectable:true,
            /*selectable: {
                month: false,
                agenda: true
            },*/
            defaultView:'${params.calView}',
            ignoreTimezone:true,
            allDayDefault:false,
            unselectAuto:false,
            editable:false,
            selectHelper: true,
            events:'${createLinkTo(dir: '/')}calendar/loadEvents/?requestuser=' +${params.requestuser?:currentUser} + '&courseSource=' + '${params.courseSource}',
            eventClick:function (event) {

                var currentView = $('#eventCal').fullCalendar('getView').name;
                var unsavedTimezone = '${unsavedTimezone}'
                    $.fancybox({
                        titleShow:false,
                        width:400,
                        height:120,
                        autoDimensions:true,
                        overlayOpacity:0.6,
                        onComplete:function () {
                            attachCalendarDatePickerClasses(event.start);
                        },
                        href:event.urlCalendar+'&calView=' + currentView + '&requestUser=' + $('#view_others').val() + '&unsavedTimezone=' + unsavedTimezone
                    });
            },

            select:function (startDate, endDate, allDay) {
                var currentView = $('#eventCal').fullCalendar('getView').name;
                if(drag && currentView=="agendaWeek") {
                    var availabilityDialog = $("<div>" +
                            '<input type="radio" id="availabilityYes" name="availability" value="true" />' + "Add Available Time" +
                            '<br/>' +
                            '<input type="radio" id="availabilityNo" name="availability" value="false"/>' + " Remove Availability" +
                            "</div>");
                    availabilityDialog.dialog({
                        title: 'Select Availability',
                        draggable: false,
                        autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,

                    });
                    availabilityDialog.dialog('open');
                    $("body").on("click", ".ui-widget-overlay", function () {
                        availabilityDialog.dialog("close");
                    });

            },
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
               var currentView = $('#eventCal').fullCalendar('getView').name;
               if(currentView=='month'){
                element.qtip({
                  // content:$(this).children('.fc-event-time').text()
                   content: event.title + "<br>" + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'MM/dd/yyyy') + "<br>" + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'h:mmTT')+ "-" +$.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, 'h:mmTT') + " " +"${calendar.userTimeZone()}"+ "<br/>Member:"+event.member
                });
                }
                if(currentView!='month'){
                 element.find('.fc-event-title').append("<br/>" + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'h:mmTT') + "-" + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, 'h:mmTT')+ " "+"${calendar.userTimeZone()} " +"<br/>Member:"+event.member);
                 }
            },

            viewDisplay: function (view) {
                currentCalendarView = view.name;
            }

        });
```

Comment: Please write code what have tried so far?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I have added the code so far. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

For this situation you have to do little tricky hack in fullcalendar.js.

First,
In agenda view there is a single full row for all days 
eg. Week start from 3rd Jan, 2016 to 9th Jan, 2016. And for 08:00 you will have single horizontal row () which start from 3rd Jan, 2016 to 9th Jan, 2016.
Here you have to make separate div blocks and set date and time as id attribute for each days within that particular single row.

Second,
On your selection bases you can apply class by getting element by id whereas id is combination of date and time.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the question as 'Can i change day cel colors based on the start or end times of the events in them. If so - yup! =)

Do some logic in eventRender and look for the dom object of the day cel using it's data-date property (in this case i highlight any days that have a event before noon):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottysmalls/s0zgayxq/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({   
        ...
        eventRender: function(event, element){
                    if (event.start.hours() < 12){
                $("td [data-date='" + event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "']").addClass('highlight-red');
              }
            },
        ...
    });
});

<style>
    #calendar .fc-day.highlight-red{
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: In the fiddle, in weekAgenda view, whole day of the week is highlighted red. what im trying to do is:
1. in Select callback im dragging the mouse to select the slots in weekAgenda view.
2. after mouse up, start time and end time is returned.
3. based on those time I want to change the color of the selected cell.

Comment: Ah - i see now. You might be able to hack it, but i don't believe there is a simple solution. The problem is that fullCalendar looks like a table with columns for dates and rows for times in the detail views but it actually isn't. There is a table for the dates and then a table for rows and they are placed on top of each other. These are just for the calendar-like appearance. The actual events and visual cues like highlights are placed using absolute positioning in layers above these. Do a search through the dom for "fc-highlight-skeleton" and you'll see what i mean.

Comment: This, unfortunately, means that it isn't really possible to set the background of the selection because there are no cels beyond the day cel. My only thought is to get the fc-highlight object after a select, clone it, note where it is located in the fc-highlight-skeleton, and then put it on another skeleton layer where it won't disappear. You may have to create a new skeleton layer to do this with similar properties to the fc-hlighlight-skeleton. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the info. i will try and do something with it.

Comment: scotty, when the following code is placed in select callback
$("#eventCal").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{
                            start: startDate,
                            end: endDate,
                            rendering: 'background',
                            block: true,
                        }, ]);
an event is created doing exactly, the same thing I wanted, whisch is to highlight the cells according to time, is there a way to implement the same thing for my problem?

Comment: If you inspect the html, you'll see that the event is placed in a layer called 'fc-content-skeleton' which lays above the html objects that create the calendar (you can confirm this by deleting 'fc-content-skeleton' - all of the events will disappear but the calendar will remain)